# Which set of commands to use to make private fork of public github repo

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to fork a public github repo but keep the fork private on my end. I've found steps for doing that here: https://gist.github.com/0xjac/85097472043b697ab57ba1b1c7530274 (and other places, but the instructions are similar)

So after doing steps 1 & 2, step 3 is to push the content to the new repo via this command:

```
git push --mirror git@github.com:<your_username>/<repo_name>.git
```

Meanwhile, the new github repo shows the standard tips, which include this:

```
...or push an existing repository from the command line:

git remote add origin git@github.com:<your_username>/<repo_name>.git
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
```

What is the difference between these 2 approaches?

1. `git push --mirror` all by itself
2. `git remote add` + a normal `git push`

Git remotes & refs kind of make my head spin. In general, I understand approach #1 and am inclined to do that but I'm not sure if it's appropriate here. Approach #2 is the recommendation but I don't understand the description of the `mirror` option in the `man` page.

**Edit:** In retrospect, I totally misunderstood the `--bare` option from step 1, which would have helped me understand the `--mirror` option later on. The `--bare` option says:

> Make a bare Git repository. That is, instead of creating <directory>
> and placing the administrative files in <directory>/.git, make the
> <directory> itself the $GIT_DIR.

This is not clearly written, IMO. I thought this meant "mix the administrative files in with the working tree", which seemed strange, but now I see it means "clone *only* administrative files, *not* the working tree".

Comment: "Github has provided steps for doing that here" No it doesn't. Those are not instructions from GitHub, it's just some individual talking (to some students?).

Comment: @matt ah, good point, I didn't notice those weren't official instructions. Updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Git remote add | git push

Pushes only the main branch in this case.

### Git push --mirror

Pushes all branches, tags and commits and creates a true mirror of the repository in your private fork.

Comment: Thank you! `man` pages are good but IMO most of them would greatly benefit from an initial description in plain language. Btw, the instructions I linked start with `git clone --bare` before doing `git push --mirror`. Is the former needed for the latter to work?

Comment: Yes, the clone `--bare --mirror` creates a local clone for the repo and it makes sure everything is therebant all branches are linked up to the correct upstream branch. And it's faster, as it doesn't create a working directory, potentially creating and extracting lots of files. Then doing a `push --mirror` pushes that whole copy to the empty repo which will be your fork.